# Using PyPy.js with Jq-console (defining stdin)

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to build an example to run simple Python code in the browser using [PyPy.js](http://pypyjs.org/). I'm able to run code and show the stdout and stderr using [Jq-console](http://replit.github.io/jq-console/). However, I have no idea on how I could get the stdin using Jq-console, if that is possible at all.

I have seen similar libraries, such as [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) and [Brython](https://brython.info) do the input using a JavaScript prompt. But I really would like to do the input from Jq-console, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Skulpt, I have and its really nice. You overwrite the standard input to be within a function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate so as to make your answer useful to readers, perhaps with an example? As is, this isn't much of an answer at all